# High GC pasue time in GC logs

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

**THIS QUESTION IS NOT ABOUT FULL GC. THIS IS ABOUT PARTIAL GC TAKING HIGH real TIME in cleaning young gen.**

I have an ongoing issue were i see VERY high GC pause time for minor GC as well. Thought the user time and sys time are very low but the real time is very high.

This may sound a dumb question but i am not sure if i understnad the reason for the same. Can someone please shed some light on the plausible causes of high real time even though we have very low user and sys time.

> 18810.228: [GC [PSYoungGen: 135430K->9574K(207360K)] 161713K->39340K(294784K), 132.4736932 secs] [Times: user=0.19
>   sys=0.20, real=**133.27 secs**]

Comment: @Modus Tollens: i would not think my question is a duplicate of the one marked as i am referen to minor GCs and not full. Thanks for the link thought.

Comment: What is the size of your heap?

Comment: -XMS 256MB and -XMX 1024MB. Total 12 process running with 12 GB RAM. Perfmon logs always indicate that at any point in time there is atleast 10 GB of free RAM sapce